# Using mysql LEFT Join DESC order is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Here i have two table,i have to join these two table and i have to get the plan details, i tried but is not happening, here is my code

**user_info**

```
id                 fullName

1                    Arun
2                    Sarvan
```

**user_active_plan**

```
id      userId    planName
1          1      Free Plan
2          1      Cool Plan
3          2      Free Plan
```

**contact_property**

```
id      userId    contactProperty
1          1      A
2          1      B
3          2      C
```

Here user_info(tablename) id (column name) i am using foreign key of user_active_plan(table name) userId(column name)

---

**I want get the latest plan based on userId,So i am using desc order , but it is not coming expected results**:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.fullName,b.*FROM user_info a LEFT JOIN user_active_plan b ON a.id = b.userId GROUP BY b.userId ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = $this->GetJoinRecord($sql);
        print_r($result);
```

I am getting the following incorrect results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fullName] => Sarvan
            [id] => 3
            [userId] => 2
            [planName] => Free Plan
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [fullName] => Arun
            [id] => 1
            [userId] => 1
            [planName] => Free Plan
        )
    )
)
```

I was expecting the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fullName] => Sarvan
            [id] => 3
            [userId] => 2
            [planName] => Free Plan
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [fullName] => Arun
            [id] => 2
            [userId] => 1
            [planName] => Coll Plan
        )
    )
)
```

> Updated Expected Answer

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userId] => 1
            [fullName] => Arun
            [planId] => 2
            [planName] => Cool Plan
            [contactCount] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [userId] => 2
            [fullName] => Sarvan
            [planId] => 3
            [planName] => Free Pla1
            [contactCount] => 1
        )

      )
```

Comment: Your `group by` is incomplete; the general group by rule is: every selected attribute has to be either in an aggregate function, or in the group by. Even though older mysql versions allow it, it does return undeterministic results. In newer mysql versions it is not allowed (unless in compatibility mode).

Comment: Arun has two plans, which one do you want to see? You said you wanted Coll Plan, but based on what criteria? When you did the grouping, you asked the query to return one of the two plans, but you didn't tell it which one, so it selected one randomly. You need to provide the criteria for selecting which plan to return.

Comment: @ Racil Hilan, I want get the latest plan based on userId,So i am using desc order , but it is not coming expected results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the latest plan with a simple subquery, no need for grouping. The count of contacts can be done with a simple grouping:

```
SELECT u.id AS userId, u.fullName, p.id AS planId, p.planName, COUNT(c.userId) AS contactCount
FROM user_info u
LEFT JOIN user_active_plan p ON u.id = p.userId
LEFT JOIN contact_property c ON u.id = c.userId
WHERE p.id = (SELECT id
              FROM user_active_plan
              WHERE userId = u.id
              ORDER BY id DESC
              LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY c.userId;
```

You can also move the condition from the `WHERE` clause to the join:

```
SELECT u.id AS userId, u.fullName, p.id AS planId, p.planName, COUNT(c.userId) AS contactCount
FROM user_info u
LEFT JOIN user_active_plan p ON u.id = p.userId
                             AND p.id = (SELECT id
                                         FROM user_active_plan
                                         WHERE userId = u.id
                                         ORDER BY id DESC
                                         LIMIT 1)
LEFT JOIN contact_property c ON u.id = c.userId
GROUP BY c.userId;
```

Comment: Thanks Bro,Thanks lot